# Copying a file to a different location

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am using a `FileDialog` to copy a picture to a location and rename it. The destination path of the folder lives with the backend file.
I occasionally get a `run-time error 75` which says `Path not found`. From the code below, `Debug.Print strBackEndPath` gives me the correct path string.
Is there a problem with the way I have used the `CopyFile` method?

```
Private Sub ItemImage_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)

Dim ofd As Object
Dim fso As Object
Dim filePath As String
Dim strExt As String
Dim strFileName
Dim strBackEndPath As String

strBackEndPath = CurrentDb.TableDefs("tblDonatedItems").Connect
strBackEndPath = Mid(Left(strBackEndPath, InStrRev(strBackEndPath, "\")), InStrRev(strBackEndPath, "=") + 1) + "ItemImages"

If Me.Dirty = True Then
Me.Dirty = False
End If

Set ofd = Application.FileDialog(3)
ofd.AllowMultiSelect = False
ofd.Show
If ofd.SelectedItems.Count = 1 Then
Set fso = VBA.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
filePath = ofd.SelectedItems(1)
strExt = Mid(ofd.SelectedItems(1), InStrRev(ofd.SelectedItems(1), "."))
strFileName = Mid(ofd.SelectedItems(1), InStrRev(ofd.SelectedItems(1), "\") + 1)
If strExt = ".jpeg" Then
strExt = ".jpg"
CopyImage filePath, Me.itemName.Value & "_" & Replace(Me.Model.Value, "/", "_") & strExt
Else
CopyImage filePath, Me.itemName.Value & "_" & Replace(Me.Model.Value, "/", "_") & strExt
End If
Else
   MsgBox "Cancel!"
End If
End Sub
```

The troubled module:

```
Sub CopyImage(filePath As String, fileName As String)
Dim fso As Object
Dim strBackEndPath As String
Dim strExt As String

strBackEndPath = CurrentDb.TableDefs("tblDonatedItems").Connect
strBackEndPath = Mid(Left(strBackEndPath, InStrRev(strBackEndPath, "\")), InStrRev(strBackEndPath, "=") + 1) + "ItemImages"
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strExt = Mid(fileName, InStrRev(fileName, "."))
Debug.Print strBackEndPath ' The correct path is given
If strExt = ".jpeg" Then
strExt = ".jpg"
fso.CopyFile filePath, strBackEndPath + "\" & fileName

Else
fso.CopyFile filePath, strBackEndPath + "\" & fileName 'Error here!
End If

Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I guess you are messed in string concatenation in `CopyFile` line. Try to make full final path first and then `Debug.Print` it.

Comment: @viilpe Even `Debug.Print strBackEndPath` just before the `Else` gives the correct path! I guess that is what you are trying to say?

Comment: I mean you should print result of `strBackEndPath + "\" & fileName` and check if it is a correct path.

Comment: @viilpe I see, problem seems to be at this line `CopyImage filePath, Me.itemName.Value & "_" & Replace(Me.Model.Value, "/", "_") & strExt`
 as a "/" is appears after renaming the file. I will use `Replace()` to see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: If you are already using FSO you should use `fso.BuildPath` to avoid confusion on when to add a slash or not: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/user-interface-help/buildpath-method

Comment: @HackSlash In my case as @viilpe pointed out there is a problem with concatenation in the `CopyImage filePath, Me.itemName.Value & "_" & Replace(Me.Model.Value, "/", "_") & strExt` line. This is because the renaming string gathered from `itemName.Value` and `Model.Value` contains a "/" character which is forbidden in file naming. Changing the lines with `CopyImage filePath, Replace (Me.itemName.Value, "/", "_") & "_" & Replace(Me.Model.Value, "/", "_") & strExt` seems to be working. @June7 once warned me about how completed it can get but Iam yet to learn from my terrible decisions.

Comment: Access has an intrinsic function FileCopy that does not require FSO. Is filename passed correctly to CopyImage sub? I think ending backslash is already in strBackEndPath so don't need to concatenate `"\"`. Step debug to check this.

Comment: @June7 the problem was the concatenation between the `itemName` and `Model` as the item name has a "/". I have used Replace method to sort this out but am not sure the problem will arise again as there are lots of forbidden characters in the itemName and Model fields.

Comment: Then maybe do Replace for every invalid character. But it still looks like to me code is concatenating an extraneous "\" character.

Comment: @June7 debug.print doesn't show any extraneous "\" character. I'm trying to construct a function to replace all special characters `*"|':!?&#~%\{}<>/` with a zero length string. So i can call the function wherever I want. Would a zero lengths string be valid in concatenation or do I need to replace them with only `_`?

Comment: I know what you are trying to do. ZLS would be a valid substitution. Alternative to Replace() is to build a table of all possible ItemName and Model pairs, assign an ID (autonumber should serve) and use that ID as the image file name.